# Asymptotic behavior of $L^2$ norm for increased matrix dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity, normed-spaces, quantum-mechanics

I am playing with matrices which are linear combinations of identity matrix, Pauli spin matrices, $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_z$ or their tensor products. For example, let the matrix be $H$. So, $H$ could be as follows.

$$H = \alpha \sigma^{\otimes n}_x + \beta \sigma^{\otimes n}_z + \gamma \hat{I}^{\otimes n}$$ where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My question is as $n \to \infty$, what will be the asymptotic behavior of $||H||_2$?

Comment: There is no such well-defined thing as  “*L* ² norm of a matrix”. There are such things as the Hilbert–Schmidt norm, *operator* norm (in *L* ² or else), and similar.